# How do i submit a hidden form using ajax when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

How can i submit a hidden form to php using ajax when the page loads?

I have a form with one hidden value which i want to submit without refreshing the page or any response message from the server. How can implement this in ajax? This is my form. I also have another form in the same page.

```
<form id = "ID_form" action = "validate.php" method = "post">
 <input type = "hidden" name = "task_id" id = "task_id" value = <?php echo $_GET['task_id'];?>>
</form>
```

Comment: Pull in the hidden value into the ajax request and send it. Are you looking for how to send an ajax request?

Comment: I dont understand why u need a form?

Comment: yes.actually, and send automatically when the page loads.

Comment: @meda,then how else can i do it

Comment: You should be able to store `$('#task_id').val()` then send that

Comment: Does it have to be POSTed? Can it be a GET request instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

similar to Zafar's answer using jQuery

actually one of the examples on the jquery site https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("validate.php", $("#ID_form").serialize());
});
```

you can .done(), .fail(), and .always() if you want to do anything with the response which you said you did not want.

in pure javascript

```
body.onload = function() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","validate.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("task_id=" + document.getElementById("task_id").value);
};
```

Comment: thank you, and the pure javascript  example is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

```
I think you have doubts invoking ajax submit at page load. Try doing this -

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        "url": "validate.php",
        "type": "post"
        "data": {"task_id": $("#task_id").val();},
        "success": function(){
        // do some action here
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you should be able to get the form and then call `submit()` on it.

E.g.:

```
var $idForm = $('#ID_form');
$idForm.submit();
```

Comment: his question specifically said he did not want the page to refresh or get a response from the server. .submit() will do both.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - jQuery AJAX post the value as others have suggested, but embed the PHP value directly. If you have multiple forms, you can add more key:value pairs as needed. Add a success/error handler if needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post( "validate.php", { task_id: "<?=$_GET['task_id']?>" } );
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, no need for a form if you want to send the data in the background.

**validate.php**

```
<?php

$task_id = $_POST['task_id'];

//perform tasks//

$send = ['received:' => $task_id]; //json format//
echo json_encode($send);
```

**JQuery/AJAX:**

```
$(function() { //execute code when DOM is ready (page load)//
    var $task = $("#task_id").val(); //store hidden value//
    $.ajax({
        url: "validate.php", //location to send data//
        type: "post",
        data: {task_id: $task},
        dataType: "json", //specify json format//
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.received); //use data received from PHP//
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="task_id" id="task_id" value=<?= $_GET['task_id'] ?>>
```